# Passing a Boost smart pointer to the thread function

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, smart-pointers

I have a situation where some object has to be passed as an argument of a thread callback function. Object is created dynamically and after it is passed to the thread, object is not needed/used in that context (in a method which starts a thread) any more. Thread function is now the only context which should own the object.

**Assuming I want to use some Boost smart pointer (instead of passing to the thread a raw pointer), which one would be the most appropriate here? What is the best practice in this case?**

What I actually need is `std::auto_ptr` with its move semantics through copy constructor. I believe that this smart pointer would perfectly fit here but it is deprecated for well-known reasons (and I cannot rely on `tr1` and `C++11` pointers; must (and want to) use *Boost* only as this code is shared between projects that must compile both in *Visual Studio 2008* and *2010*).

`boost::shared_ptr` is an option - I could pass it by value but think it would be overkilling. **Is there any chance of emulating move semantics (in a safe way) with `boost::scoped_ptr`?** I don't need reference counting here as am not sharing object between two contexts, I just want to transfer the ownership over object from one context to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [boost::interprocess::unique_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/interprocess/interprocess_smart_ptr.html#interprocess.interprocess_smart_ptr.unique_ptr), or write your own `unique_ptr` using [Boost.Move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/move.html).

`boost::interprocess::unique_ptr` uses Boost.Move in its implementation, and Boost.Move emulates C++11 move semantics C++03.

Comment: I'll have a look at `boost::interprocess::unique_ptr` now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr` works well for most situations (including yours). You can use this pattern:

```
shared_ptr<MyT> param = .....;
thread = boost::thread(thread_routine, param);
param.reset();
```

... and now only thread_routine holds the object.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of this solution and in my case I even don't need to call `reset` as `param` immediately goes out of the scope (that function returns as soon as thread is created). But I was wondering if Boost had any non-reference-count smart pointer that supports move semantics. Seems that `boost::interprocess::unique_ptr` is what I want.